# Unable to retrieve data from firebase database into heroku app

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, heroku, firebase-realtime-database

I've created a angular app: [todolistapp](https://silvercyber-todo-list.herokuapp.com/). The tasks are being saved in a firebase database and can be seen under Your Tasks heading.

The application is working fine on localhost but after deploying it on heroku, It is not showing the tasks. Check this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Lr06.png).

What am I doing wrong?

This is the full error shown in the screenshot:

```
ERROR TypeError: Ia.Observable is not a constructor
    at Aa (main.c0eb70b5514f5eed42fe.js:1)
    at main.c0eb70b5514f5eed42fe.js:1
    at Fa (main.c0eb70b5514f5eed42fe.js:1)
    at Object.snapshotChanges (main.c0eb70b5514f5eed42fe.js:1)
    at t.ngOnInit (main.c0eb70b5514f5eed42fe.js:1)
    at Ne (main.c0eb70b5514f5eed42fe.js:1)
    at Oe (main.c0eb70b5514f5eed42fe.js:1)
    at xe (main.c0eb70b5514f5eed42fe.js:1)
    at Hn (main.c0eb70b5514f5eed42fe.js:1)
    at ur (main.c0eb70b5514f5eed42fe.js:1)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "todolistapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^4.6.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.2",
    "npm": "6.14.4"
  }
}
```

environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "SOME_CREDENTIALS",
    authDomain: "SOME_CREDENTIALS",
    databaseURL: "SOME_CREDENTIALS",
    projectId: "SOME_CREDENTIALS",
    storageBucket: "SOME_CREDENTIALS",
    messagingSenderId: "SOME_CREDENTIALS",
    appId: "SOME_CREDENTIALS",
    measurementId: "SOME_CREDENTIALS"
  }
};
```

server.js

```
//Install express server
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve only the static files form the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/todolistapp'));

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/todolistapp/index.html'));
});

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Comment: There's an error message showing in the screenshot, but unfortunately you didn't include all of it. Please copy the full error message and stack trace from the browser, and add it to your question (as text, no screenshots please).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ya just added the full error in the question. Check it please .

Comment: That's a stack trace from minified code, making it almost impossible to map to any code you shared. I wonder if the minification isn't the cause of your problem, so you might want to see if you can reproduce it locally with a minified/release version of your app (and thus rule out Heroku as a possible cause).